# How do I access to the resources in the Fluent Ribbon Control Suite?

Tags: wpf, fluent, fluent-ribbon

I'm developing a WPF application that uses the [Fluent Ribbon Control Suite](http://fluent.codeplex.com) and i'd like to use its 'themes' in the rest of the application.

Specifically, when you choose to use the Blue theme

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Fluent;Component/Themes/Office2010/Blue.xaml" />
```

I would like to use some of the colours inside that file, to style other interface elements (buttons, popups etc).

Any idea how I might do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, but it's not ideal…

1. Downloaded the Source Code from [here](http://fluent.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) and open it up in Blend.
2. Using the Resources tab, browse the different ResourceDictionary file (ColorsBlue.xaml, Button.xaml etc.)
3. Make a note of the resource keys for the resources you want.
4. In your original application add the styles/colours etc you want.
5. Now whenever you change the theme (Blue/Black/Silver etc) it will automatically change the background colour of your controls!

Hope that helps.